# Is there a fork of Python Social Auth that supports Django 1.9 or 1.10 under Python 3.5?

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I see a lot of issues and pull requests on the python social auth repo, all of which have not been acted on and the django app itself hasn't been updated in over 2 years.

Is there a fork of the project to which the compatibility changes have already been applied?